# Randomized algorithm for verifying eigenvector

Tags: probability, algorithms

Is there a simple way to verify whether a vector is an eigenvector for a matrix A using a randomized algorithm? How fast can this be done ? What is the probability of error ?

Comment: The simple way is to multiply the vector by $A$. How much leeway do you have on simplicity, speed and error?

Comment: I'm looking for a similar improvement like the one for verifying matrix multiplication which can be done in $\theta(n^2)$ time.